# Why powershell command Mount-DiskImage results in "Access Denied"

Tags: powershell, vhd

I have a VHDX file on my Win10.21H2 PC. When I boot into my Windows desktop, and execute the following command as Administrator, I got "Access Denied".

```
powershell Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath K:\WSL-vhdx\WSL-Ubuntu-2204.vhdx
```

But, if I run diskmgmt.msc and do "Attach VHD"(it succeeds) then "Detach VHD", then go back to execute the very powershell command, the command succeeds this time.

Can someone tell me how to have my `Mount-DiskImage` succeed without the help of diskmgmt.msc ?

[image: powershell Mount-DiskImage command]

Comment: Do you (the user, not the system) have write/full control of the folder where the image is located?

Comment: Sure, I, even if not RunAsAdmin, can copy K:\WSL-vhdx\WSL-Ubuntu-2204.vhdx to other folders, operating in Explorer UI.

Comment: Are you running as Admin?

Comment: Is the WSL instance by chance automatically starting when the user is logged into? PowerShell 5.1 or PowerShell 7.X?

Comment: After I rebooted Windows someday, this problem has gone. So it is still unclear why that happened.